# What is a django alternative to {% include %} tag

Tags: django

In the django doc it is mentioned that {% include %} is deprecated since 1.11. Since I'm new to django, what is the alternative? Imagine you have a header of a page which is different if you are authenticated or not. I do not want to have both layouts in the header.html template...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{% include %}` is not being deprecated

Any exceptions raised when rendering the included template will now be raised instead of being silenced

> Deprecated since version 1.11:
>   Silencing exceptions raised while rendering the {% include %} template tag is deprecated. In Django 2.1,
>   the exception will be raised

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish what you want I would suggest this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'myprofile' %}"> My Profile</a></li>
{% else %}     
  <li><a  href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li> 
  <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
  <li><a class="fa fa-cog" href="{% url 'settings' %}" target="_blank"> Settings</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

So your header.html/base.html will know if the user is logged in and switches the attributes of the header.

Hope that helps :)